# OpenMP - Parallelism and Nested Loops

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, openmp

Currently, I'm trying to implement an algorithm the Laplace equation. I've looked at several implementations, and I'm stuck at what would be the best place to place OpenMP's pragma declaration.

```
while( var > tol && iter <= maxIter ) {
    ++iter;
    var = 0.0;

    for (i=1; i<=n; ++i)
        for (j=1; j<=n; ++j) {         
            Tnew[i*n2+j] = 0.25*( T[(i-1)*n2+j] + T[(i+1)*n2+j] 
                                + T[i*n2+(j-1)] + T[i*n2+(j+1)] );

            var = fmax(var, fabs(Tnew[i*n2+j] - T[i*n2+j]));
        }
}
```

Personally, I believe that the best case would be placing it just before the inner loop, since I believe it would cause no dependency issues. However, a friend told me that it would be too costly. What's the best way to go about this, and why?

Comment: And what have you tried so far? What were the benchmarked results for respective approaches and what is your target performance expectation you strive to meet?

Comment: No dependency issues? Did you look at your code or published examples eg red black scheme?

Comment: I believe there should be one more loop where you assign values of Tnew to T.

Comment: Your code sample has no data dependency, you can put it on the outermost loop if you like. But as n-canter points out .. where do you update T? This serial code doesn't seem to be doing the right thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I think that you have forgotten to swap the arrays `Tnew` and `T` at the end of all the outer-loop iterations.
Assuming that these are pointers, here is the rectified serial code:

```
while(var > tol && iter <= maxIter) {
    ++iter;
    var = 0.0;
    for (i=1; i<=n; ++i)
        for (j=1; j<=n; ++j) {         
            Tnew[i*n2+j] = 0.25*(T[(i-1)*n2+j] + T[(i+1)*n2+j] 
                                + T[i*n2+(j-1)] + T[i*n2+(j+1)]);
            var = fmax(var, fabs(Tnew[i*n2+j] - T[i*n2+j]));
        }
    }
    temp = TNew;
    TNew = T;
    T = temp;
}
```

Now, you might want to attempt parallelization of the `i`-loop. Note that `var` must be a shared variable, hence there will race on its updates in the innermost parallel region; we will use a `critical` construct to ensure atomicity. Here is the näive code:

```
while(var > tol && iter <= maxIter) {
    ++iter;
    var = 0.0;
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for (i=1; i<=n; ++i)
        for (j=1; j<=n; ++j) {         
            Tnew[i*n2+j] = 0.25*(T[(i-1)*n2+j] + T[(i+1)*n2+j] 
                                + T[i*n2+(j-1)] + T[i*n2+(j+1)]);
            #pragma omp critical
            {
                var = fmax(var, fabs(Tnew[i*n2+j] - T[i*n2+j]));
            }
        }
    }
    temp = TNew;
    TNew = T;
    T = temp;
}
```

As your friend correctly pointed out, the overheads of thread creation/termination can be high if the `parallel` region is created and destroyed a large number of times. Hence, with the help of `master` or `single` construct, we should now attempt to move this parallel construct outside the outermost loop. Here is the example translation:

```
#pragma omp parallel private(iter) shared(var, maxIter)
{   
    while(var > tol && iter <= maxIter) {
        ++iter;
        #pragma omp barrier
        #pragma omp single
        {
            var = 0.0;
        }
        #pragma omp for
        for (i=1; i<=n; ++i)
            for (j=1; j<=n; ++j) {         
                Tnew[i*n2+j] = 0.25*(T[(i-1)*n2+j] + T[(i+1)*n2+j] 
                                    + T[i*n2+(j-1)] + T[i*n2+(j+1)]);
                #pragma omp critical
                {
                    var = fmax(var, fabs(Tnew[i*n2+j] - T[i*n2+j]));
                }
            }
        }
        #pragma omp single
        {
            temp = TNew;
            TNew = T;
            T = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

Note that it is important to privatize `iter`. Also note that the explicit and implicit barriers ensure that there is no race among different accesses to `var`, `TNew` and `T`.

*About `critical` construct:* Note that it can be costly to call critical region a large number of times inside the innermost loop. You should use a private variable to obtain the max difference for each thread, and then use a critical region *outside* the for loops to obtain the correct value of `var`. I'll leave the actual translation to you.

**Suggestion**: Test this code for some big data-set, i.e., for some big values of `n` (about 500-2000) and small values of `tol` (about 0.01-0.001), to see any visible speedup as compared to the serial code; otherwise, the synchronization cost might neutralize any parallelism gains, rendering the parallel version less efficient than the serial one.